# How to size a view to the maximum limits while keeping it centered

Tags: wpf

I have a listview that stays centered in the form like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Like this, the ListView will automatically take up more space as it grows and will automatically display a ScrollBar when it reaches the limits of the form.

Q: How can I make the ListView take up all the available vertical space, even when it's empty (reducing rows 0 and 2 to 0px).

I do not want to change the RowDefinitions because actually, instead of this one ListView I have several views which can be displayed in the same Grid. Some should be able to automatically grow (while staying centered) while others should take up all the available space. I'm looking for something like `<ListView Height="Maximum" />` or so.

Comment: I cannot set the RowSpan because the actual ListView in my actual situation is nested within a ContentControl. It's really a situation where I can dynamically put any view I wish into this setup.

Comment: As per my understanding, you want to reserve first row for header, second row for content and third row for footer. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @Sham The first and the third row are empty (transparent) and are there only to center the second row, which contains a view (ex the ListView in this example) that has its own header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the window height to a property in the ViewModel, then set that to the `MinHeight` of the `ListView`, like so:

```
<Window
    ...
    Height="{Binding MaxHeight}">
```

then:

```
<ListView MinHeight="{Binding MaxHeight}" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used below skeleton in many applications.

Now First and third row take the space required for them and second row covers the leftover space

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListView Grid.Row="1" />
```